# Problem on the euclidean connection and its affine differentiations.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

I am thinking of this interesting problem, seems to be easy but finally its not.

Let $\nabla$ the euclidean connection on $ \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\Omega= \{ f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n | \ \ f \ \ is \ \ diffeomorphism, f_*(\nabla_XY)=\nabla_{f_*X}f_*Y \}$. Then the functions in $\Omega$ are of the form $Ax + b$ where $A \in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$  and $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Of course in this situation, $f_*$ is a linear trasformation, so we know that $f_* \in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$. But what can we say about $f$?

Comment: As you write it, $f_*$ is the push-forward on vector fields, so this is like $(f_*X)(x)=Df(x)(X(x))$ and it is just $Df(x)$ which is linear for each $x$. The key issue in the problem is to prove that $Df(x)$ is independent of $x$, i.e. that $D^2f=0$.

Comment: The confusion starts when you try to translate the fact that the diffeomorphism preserves the connection, what does this really mean?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Viewing vector fields on $\mathbb R^n$ as functions $X:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$, the connection is given by $(\nabla_XY)(x)=DY(x)(X(x))$ and the push forward is given by $(f_*X)(x)=Df(x)(X(x))$. Using this, you can work out what compatibility with the connection actually means.